# Unable to escape quotes in terraform when writing cloudwatch subscription filter patterns

Tags: escaping, terraform

I've got the following terraform resource declaration:

```
# Log subscription to lambda
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "subscription" {
  provider = "aws.west"
  name            = "root-monitor"
  log_group_name  = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log-group.name}"
  filter_pattern  = "{ $.userIdentity.type = \"Root\" && ( $.eventType = \"AwsConsoleSignIn\" || ( $.eventType = \"AwsApiCall\" && $.userIdentity.accessKeyId = \"*\" )) }"
  destination_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
}
```

Note that the expression must contain double-quotes. The terraform must also be enclosed in double-quotes, so I've tried escaping with a backslash. (This is to say, neither the filter expression nor terraform accept single-quote as an alternative).

This is accepted and pushed successfully to aws, but the resulting pattern contains the backslashes:

```
$ aws logs describe-subscription-filters --log-group-name cloudtrail-root-monitor
{
    "subscriptionFilters": [
        {
            "filterName": "root-monitor",
            "logGroupName": "cloudtrail-root-monitor",
            "filterPattern": "{ $.userIdentity.type = \"Root\" && ( 
$.eventType = \"AwsConsoleSignIn\" || ( $.eventType = \"AwsApiCall\" && $.userIdentity.accessKeyId = \"*\" ))}",
            "destinationArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:root-alarm-processor",
            "distribution": "ByLogStream",
            "creationTime": 1506386842242
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried it the filter pattern as a docstring and unfortunately arrive at the same result.

Any help is appreciated. I've resorted to issuing a provisioner but in a multi-account setup it's a pain. Thank you.

Comment: take a look on format() function. if still can't fix the issue, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In what context are you referring to this function? I'm not seeing this in the terraform documentation.

Comment: Anectodally, the provisioner works fine - it was a pain because I'd failed to add the provider to the cloudwatch_log resource. Doesn't change the root problem, which in my use case appears to be undesired behavior, but it does satisfy my requirement overall.

Comment: the port of `filter_pattern` , change to `filter_pattern = '${format("%s.....", <pattern>)}"`

Comment: see also https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1779

Comment: @lunix_captain were you able to find the solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

So as I couldn't find a 100% clear answer in the comments above I paste here what worked for me. (The exact string I wanted to match is `"(0, 0)"`).

`pattern = "${format("\"%s\"", "(0, 0)")}"`

Comment: Do you not see backslashes in your filter pattern? I am still seeing backslash in terraform plan

Comment: No, the result in the AWS console is (including the quotes): `"(0, 0)"`